# Cannot convert content scheme uri to file path

Tags: android, file

I put `.jpg` , `.pdf` , `.docx` , `.xlx` , `.mp3` , `.mp4`  type of fine on same location of sd-card (External memory card)

When i try to choose file then i able to choose only `.jpg` , .pdf file other type of file not choosen

Chosen file :->

```
 1.path : `/storage/emulated/0/123.pdf`  (from this path i successfully attached file)
 2. path : `/storage/emulated/0/Program.docx`                        
 3. path : `/storage/emulated/0/ApiCalling.mp4`
```

Error is :

> file are not exists.. when i get 2. and 3. number of path

Code is :

```
 public static void showFileChooser(Context context) {
    PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 2;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, context.getResources().getString(R.string.select_file_msg)),
                PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
       e.print();
    }
}
```

---

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
Uri uri = data.getData();
         try {
                String path = Utility.getRealPathFromURI(this, uri);
                Log.e("path -> ",path);
                File f = new File(path);
                if (f.exists()) {
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e("err -> ","file not exists");
                }
            }
    }
```

---

```
public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    // Uri is different in versions after KITKAT (Android 4.4), we need to
    if (uri != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context.getApplicationContext(), uri)) {
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                selection = "_id=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };
            }
        }

        if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            String[] projection = {
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
            };
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                        .query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return cursor.getString(column_index);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/123.pdf`. That is not a path to a file on a micro SD card but to external storage.

Comment: `intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);`. Maybe you should remove that.

Comment: i also try this 
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
then also not get file

Comment: `path : /storage/emulated/0/ApiCalling.mp4

Error is :

file are not exists..`?? Who/what is giving that error? Never seen that error. Did you quote it ok?

Comment: `not selected file path : /storage/emulated/0/Program.docx`. It is unclear what you mean. Can the user see the .docx file in the list?

Comment: `i also try this intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE); then also not get file`. ???? You already tried that. I just asked you to do without.

Comment: yes i do this without intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);   but then also not choose file

Comment: i mean at activityresult  when i get file from path with non pdf or jpg extension that give exception file not exists   
by the way physically file are available on this location 
i get "/storage/emulated/0/Program.docx"  this path from activity result 

String path = Utility.getRealPathFromURI(this, uri);
                    Log.e("path -> ",path);
                    File f = new File(path);
                    if (f.exists()) {}else{   " file not exists"    }

Comment: Please put that code in your post as it unreadable now. And edit your post as you confused us. The user CAN choose a .docx file! Only your code handles it wrong.  Rephrase your problem please.

Comment: Not only code. Rephrase your problem as the user CAN choose all kind of files. Also change the subject as the user CAN choose mp4 files too.

Comment: Your problem/subject: Cannot convert content scheme uri to file path.

Comment: You are still telling that the user cannot choose some files. Which is not true. You are still talking about a selected file path although that path is not selected but a result from your code. You are still talking about an sd card which quite clearly is not used here. I asked you to edit your post and tell a good story. I wait for that.

Comment: getRealPathFromURI() works great for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no guarantee that the content the user selected is on external storage and/or is backed by a file. Even if it is, chances are you don't have access to it. But you can simply use [`ContentResolver.openInputStream()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream(android.net.Uri)) with the Uri from the data field of the result Intent to read the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent mediaIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
mediaIntent.setType("*/*"); //set mime type as per requirement
startActivityForResult(mediaIntent,REQUESTCODE_PICK_FILE);
```

Then you can get path in onActivityResult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUESTCODE_PICK_FILE
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri videoUri = data.getData();
        Log.d("", "Video URI= " + videoUri);


    }
}
```